# A question about inherited orientation of simplices

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have the 2-manifold $[v_2,v_0,v_3]$. My books says that on removing $v_3$, the orientation of the face that we end up with is $[v_0,v_2]$.

I don't understand how this happens. What is the procedure that was followed? Is it possible that the author has oriented $1$-simplices differently from what the inherited orientation would be?

Note: One might be tempted to think that the procedure involves multiplication by $(-1)^3$, or in other words, $(-1)^a$ where $a$ is he index of the removed vertex. However, my book also says that removing the vertex $v_1$ from $[v_0,v_1,v_3]$ gives us $[v_0,v_3]$. Hence, this procedure does not seem to be followed.

Comment: What book is this?  This seems like the opposite of the standard convention for orienting boundary faces of a simplex...

Comment: @EricWofsey- This is "An Introduction to Algebraic Topology" by John W. Keesee. Could you tell me inducing an orientation on a face is well-defined?

Comment: @EricWofsey- In the sense that if I perform an even number of permutations on the vertices of a simplex, the orientation induced on a face would be the same both before and after the permutations..?

Comment: Yes, it is well-defined; the standard definition is to orient a boundary face multiplying by $(-1)^a$ where $a$ is the index of the removed vertex _when you count vertices starting from $0$_.  So when you remove $v_3$ from $[v_2,v_0,v_3]$, $a$ would be $2$, and when you remove $v_1$ from $[v_0,v_1,v_3]$, $a$ would be $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you say the multiplication by $(-1)^a$ procedure is not being followed.  In the case of removing the vertex $v_1$ from $[v_0,v_1,v_3]$, $a$ would be $2$ (since $v_1$ is the second vertex), so you would end up with $[v_0,v_3]$.  So it seems that this is indeed the rule your book is following.

(Beware, however, that this is not the convention used by most authors.  The standard convention would be to multiply by $(-1)^a$ where $a$ is the index of the vertex being removed, where you start indexing the vertices from $0$ rather than from $1$.  That is, the standard convention is to give all the boundary faces the opposite orientation from what your book seems to be giving them.)